# Django template compare two variables not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I am building a pagination with Django and Bootstrap. There is this variable pageNum which is passed from my views.py and indicates the current page. I use a for loop to generate the pagination. The pagination itself is fine but when I compare forloop.counter to pageNum to add the class="active" to the current li its not working. But when I actually print the values of pageNum and forloop.counter they are identical. Here is the code:

```
 <ul class="pagination">
 {% for pagination in paginationInfo %}
      <li {% if forloop.counter == pageNum %} class="active" {%endif%} ><a href="{{pagination}}">{{forloop.counter}}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Could you show your view where you are calculating and passing this `pageNum`?

Comment: It is a GET variable. My bad. I used int(pageNum) in views for calculations but I was passing the raw (string type) pageNum to the template.

Comment: So instead of using `pageNum|add:"0"` in the template which I don't think is the ideal solution here, you could pass the integer value in the template and then everything will work fine. I say this because then if you again want to use `pageNum` somewhere else in the template you might forget that it is not `int`.

Comment: AKS is right. As I suggested in my answer you should cast your variable to `int`. That would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you. I am correcting the views. I could happen again in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably passing the `pageNum` as string into the template. To compare it, you need to cast it into an `int` in your view or use the `add` filter:

```
<ul class="pagination">
 {% for pagination in paginationInfo %}
    <li {% if forloop.counter == pageNum|add:"0" %} class="active" {%endif%} ><a href="{{pagination}}">{{forloop.counter}}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Confirmed, both casting to an `int` in the view `upvote_count_int = int(upvote_count)`, and adding the number `0` to the template (as above) works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have one of the fields as a different data type. In my case one of the items was a string and you cannot compare a string to an integer so I had to coerce the string into an integer see below

```
{% if questions.correct_answer|add:"0" == answers.id %}
    <span>Correct</span>
{% endif %}
```