# Django template variable conditionals don't evaluate properly?

Tags: django, templates, variables

This makes no apparent sense to me.  As you can see in the code below, I am pulling customer subscription data from various page context objects in django. As you can see in the attached screenshot, the variables work, and (unless django template variable values are type casted?) the values do in fact match.

Based on the if condition, the customer (user object)'s existing subscription should be classed "active" when the page loads, but it isn't?

```
<div class="card-deck">
    {% for product in products %}
    request.user.is_paysubscribed = {{ request.user.is_paysubscribed }}<br />
    product.metadata.tier = {{ product.metadata.tier }}<br />
    <div class="card mb-4">
     {% for price in product.plan_set.all %}
     <div class="card-body{% if request.user.is_paysubscribed == product.metadata.tier %} active"{% else %}"{% endif %} id="{{ product.name|slugify }}-card" role="button" onclick="planSelect('{{ product.name|slugify }}-card', '{{ product.name }}', '{{ price.human_readable_price }}', '{{ price.id }}')">
      <h5 class="card-title text-center"><label for="{{ product.name }}">redacted product name</label></h5>
      <p class="text-center">{{ price.human_readable_price }}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: the values ***are*** type casted.  In my case `user.is_paysubscribed` is an int field in the database, and `product.metadata.tier` is just extra fluff added to a Stripe product's freeform fields, so is (probably) returned as a string.

Found the solution to cast them both as ints in this reply to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36808765/7488096

the `|(math):value` filters in django re-cast the value as an int.

so, `|add:"0"` makes them both ints and the comparison then works.